# How to properly host React SPA application as IIS application?

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router

I have React application created via Create React App which I need to host on IIS as a application on IIS Default Web Site.

My react application is using react-router 4 and it's `BrowserRouter` for client-side navigation, however it's not working properly.

Example app code - https://github.com/mandrive/react-router-iis-problem

On IIS I'm hosting my app under URL: `http://localhost/myapp` (it is Default Web Site on port 80 on IIS, and myapp is IIS Application)

I need to host application like this on multiple different servers as IIS Application without specifying environment specific values for `package.json` `homepage` or `BrowserRouter` `basename` - so it should work without any environment-specific changes in source code before/after build on CI.

I'm aware of IIS rewriting - I'm doing exactly like it is described here https://medium.com/@mateioprea/setting-up-a-react-app-with-react-router-in-iis-71cb86aee376

The only way I'm getting this to work properly is when I specify `package.json` `"homepage": "./"` and `<BrowserRouter basename="myapp">` - which I don't want to, because then I will need to replace those values for each different environments I want to deploy this app.

Is this possible? Does React SPA can be hosted without such environment-specific changes on IIS?

Comment: did you find a solution?